# Approximate distribution of product of N normal i.i.d.? Special case μ≈0

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, asymptotics, approximation

Given 
$N\geq30$ i.i.d. $X_n\approx\mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$, 
and $\mu_X \approx 0$,
looking for:

1. accurate closed form distribution approximation of
   $Y_N=\prod\limits_{1}^{N}{X_n}$
2. asymptotic ([exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)?) approximation of same product

This is a special case $\mu_X \approx 0$ of a more [general question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144913/approximate-distribution-of-product-of-n-normal-i-i-d-general-case).

Comment: 1. Do you have any information about the $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X$?  (It would be nice if all $\mu_X/\sigma_X \gg 0$, for instance.) (2) An asymptotic normal approximation will be *horrible*, because asymptotically $Y$ will not look remotely normal.

Comment: I just had a quick play with this. If you are interested, it is possible to obtain an exact closed form solution for the product of $n$ random variables that are iid $N(0, \sigma^2)$. The non-zero $\mu$ case makes things much more complicated.

Comment: @whuber

**(1)** after doing some monte carlo with some different $\mu$ and $\sigma$, 
I found that distribution of $F$ behaves rather well for $N>30$ and $|\mu_X|\geq10\sigma_X$;
now I would like to find a nice *expression* for $\mu_F$ and $\sigma_F$
similar to how ${\chi}^2$ has few nice approximations. I built few approximations via taylor expansion, but they misbehave badly.

**(2)** well, $F$ definitely "looks" like a sum of normal with chi squared, so $F$ can be reduced to normal, if approximation "proves" that.

Comment: When $\mu_X \ge 10\sigma_X$, $Y$ will be nicely approximated by a lognormal distribution (as an application of the [Barry-Esseen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) to $\log(X)$ shows).

Comment: @whuber direct application of Barry-Esseen gives $F_N \approx 0 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}Z$, which is nice indeed, but it looses some structure: $\mu_F$ should be negative, $\sigma_F$ should depend on $\alpha$, etc. perhaps, there are better ways of applying it?

Comment: Would a saddlepoint expansion work?

Comment: @seanv507 sure. can you recommend existing java/scala library or verified numerical algorithm source for saddlepoint/mgf approach designed for relatively small sample size?

Comment: The book https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Distributions-Involving-Gaussian-Variables/dp/0387346570   contains exact moment generating function, then you can continue with saddlepoint approximation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to obtain an exact solution in the zero-mean case (part B).

**The Problem**

Let $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ denote $n$ iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$ variables, each with common  pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

We seek the pdf of $\prod_{i=1}^n X_i$, for $n = 2, 3, \dots$

**Solution**

The pdf of the product of two such Normals is simply:

[image]

... where I am using the  `TransformProduct` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*. The domain of support is:

[image]

The product of 3, 4, 5 and 6 Normals is obtained by iteratively applying the same function (here four times):

[image]

... where `MeijerG` denotes the [Meijer G function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html)

By induction, the pdf of the product of $n$ iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables is:

---

$$\frac{1}{(2 \pi )^{\frac{n}{2}} \sigma ^n} \text{MeijerG}[\{ \{ \},  \{ \} \}, \{ \{0_1, \dots, 0_n \}, \{ \} \}, \frac{x^2}{2^n \sigma ^{2 n}}] \quad \quad \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R} $$

---

**Quick Monte Carlo check**

Here is a quick check comparing:

- the theoretical pdf just obtained (when $n = 6$ and $\sigma=3$):  RED DASHED curve
- to the empirical Monte Carlo pdf:  squiggly BLUE curve

[image]

Looks fine! [ the blue squiggly Monte curve is obscuring the exact red-dashed curve ]

Comment: Outstanding, thank you, Colin. Now I see why I must buy [your book](http://www.amazon.com/Colin-Rose/e/B001HCXA02/) :-) Also makes me wonder if $log(...MeijerG(...))$ looks any simpler. Time to dust off my Wolfram skills.