# Approximate distribution of product of N normal i.i.d.? General case

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, asymptotics, approximation

Given 
$N\geq30$ i.i.d. $X_n\approx\mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$, 
and NO assumptions about $\mu_X$ and $\sigma_X$,
looking for:

1. accurate closed form distribution approximation of
   $Y_N=\prod\limits_{1}^{N}{X_n}$
2. asymptotic ([exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)?) approximation of same product

This is a general case, there are also some special cases:

A) [$\mu_X \approx 0$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144684/approximate-distribution-of-product-of-n-normal-i-i-d-special-case-%CE%BC%E2%89%880)

B) [$\mu_X > 10 \sigma_X > 0$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144958/approximate-distribution-of-product-of-n-normal-i-i-d-special-case-%CE%BC10%CF%83-%CF%830)

Comment: Please elaborate & clarify your post. Eg, is it a question? (There is no question mark.) What question are you asking, perchance?

Comment: this is relocation placeholder for first answer by [wolfies](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/24905/wolfies), see [original question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144684/approximate-distribution-of-product-of-n-normal-i-i-d) and relocation request by [whuber](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)

Comment: Please add whatever context is necessary to understand your question to this post.

Comment: The special cases are nearly meaningless, because the problem does not change when you change the units of measure of $X$. Thus condition (A) asserts nothing and condition $B$ merely asserts $\mu_X\ne 0$.