# PDF of sums, products of iid Normals

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, modeling, finance, convolution

I've recently taken to looking at the distribution of a financial time series of the form 
$$X_t = X_{t-1}(1+W_t)$$
 where $W_t$ is iid $N(0,\sigma^2)$.  Expanding the equation out we get 
$$X_t = X_0\prod_{k=1}^t (1+W_k)$$
And multiplying out the right-hand side gives us:
$$X_t = X_0 \Big(1+\sum_{i=1}^t W_i + \sum_{i\neq j}W_iW_j + \sum_{i\neq j \neq k}W_iW_jW_k + \cdots + \prod W_i\Big)$$
Now I know that the product of n iid random normals $W_1*\cdots*W_n$ has pdf:
$$f_W(w) = (2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}\exp \bigg(\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}w^Tw \bigg)$$
So my question is, how would one go about finding the pdf of $X_t$, which is the sum of several of these variables (with repetitive $W_i$ terms)?

As a second question, is there is there a less intensive way to model a financial time series?  I've heard of GARCH models, but I would love to hear what others might use to study the behavior of stocks.

Comment: "Now I know that the product of $n$ iid normal random variables... has pdf ...."  Alas, it is not so. What you have written down is the pdf of the _sum_ of $n$ $N(0,\sigma^2)$ random variables and not the product. What you need is the pdf of $\prod_i (1+W_i) = \prod_i V_i$ where the $V_i$ are iid $N(1,\sigma^2)$ random variables.

Comment: Many similar Qs, one is https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144684/approximate-distribution-of-product-of-n-normal-i-i-d-special-case-%ce%bc%e2%89%880